# D3 convert geojson to topojson syntax

Tags: syntax, d3.js

I am following the syntax to convert geojson to topojson as described here

https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference

I want to make sure the properties are on the generated topojson file so that I can access that info later on in the code.
The problem is none of it is getting generated with the topojson code.
What am I missing?

```
topojson -o zone1994topojson.json -p W6ID,W_NAME,EASE_WORED,EASE_Z4ID,EASE_ZONEN,REGION_NAM,REGION_R2I,AREA_KM
2,LAT_HI,LONG_HI,LAT_LOW,LONG_LOW zone1994.json
```